# How to deserilize this result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have created one aspx page which I am giving to vendor.They will pass json object to that my url in this format.

```
[{
    "count":"2",
    "data":[{
        "Name": "Pinky",
        "number": "91XXXX",
        "place": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rohan",
        "number": "91XXXX",
        "place": "Pune"
    }]
}]
```

How to deserilize above.I am able to deserilize below

```
{
    "Name": "Pinky",
    "number": "91XXXX",
    "place": "Mumbai"
}
```

Class :

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the json string represents an object with a two members: a count, and a member called "data" containing the list items. Your data structure models only a single list item. You could create a second class with a layout that matches the json data, containing an `IList<Student> data`, and deserialize into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such cases it is useful to use a website such as this:  http://json2csharp.com/
to create C# classes from your json output.

This will show you that you will need a wrapper around your Student class.  So you have the following

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string count { get; set; }
    public List<Student> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialise into your `RootObject`

Comment: Thanks jason.kaisersmith,for ur help.I already used this site for deserilization,But it is showing me error for above script.

Comment: I had a issue that in your text the double quote was somehow corrupted,  I assumed that this was a copy paste error, so I replaced it manually.  And used https://jsonlint.com/ to verify the JSON.

Comment: Hi @Jason ,thanks.Yes ,u  right.That was copied paste.I replaced " with proper ".It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

this helps you too..

```
string jstring = "[{\"count\":\"2\",\"data\":[ {\"Name\": \"Pinky\",\"number\": \"91XXXX\",\"place\": \"Mumbai\"},{\"Name\": \"Rohan\",\"number\": \"91XXXX\",\"place\": \"Pune\"} ]}]";
var rootArray = JArray.Parse(jstring);
List<Student> dataList = rootArray[0]["data"].ToObject<List<Student>>();
```